# How to construct firewall rule from 52.112.0.0/14

Tags: ip

I am trying to create a firewall rule to allow Microsoft Teams thru my firewall. I can see here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide#skype-for-business-online-and-microsoft-teams

that 52.112.0.0/14 is the address used but the ip that is recorded in my router is 52.113.89.125.

The 89.125 can change from time to time but when I looked it up on   https://ipinfo.io/52.113.89.125 its 'route' is 52.112.0.0/14...

I would like to be able to create a fire wall rule for this but I am unsure of what 52.112.0.0/14 means and how to construct the firewall rule

Comment: This is not really about firewalls or security. This is really just about IP addressing. as the answer below shows. This would have been better asked on a networking site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `52.112.0.0/14` is *Classless Inter-domain Routing* CIDR notation ([RFC 4632](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4632)).

The [IP Calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=52.112.0.0&mask1=14) by Krischan Jodies illustrates this nicely:

> ```
> Address:   52.112.0.0            00110100.01110000.00000000.00000000
> Netmask:   255.252.0.0 = 14      11111111.11111100.00000000.00000000
> Wildcard:  0.3.255.255           00000000.00000011.11111111.11111111
> =>
> Network:   52.112.0.0/14         00110100.01110000.00000000.00000000
> Broadcast: 52.115.255.255        00110100.01110011.11111111.11111111
> HostMin:   52.112.0.1            00110100.01110000.00000000.00000001
> HostMax:   52.115.255.254        00110100.01110011.11111111.11111110
> Hosts/Net: 262142
> ```

As `52.112.0.0/14` has host range `52.112.0.1`-`52.115.255.254`, the `52.113.89.125` belongs to it.

But just allowing `52.112.0.0/14` is not enough, as the site lists several ranges for the service. You would have to add them all in your rules to make it work reliably.

A firewall could be many things: it is impossible to tell how to construct rules for your firewall.

Comment: thanks..my router allows for Range Address and if 52.112.0.0/14 covers 52.112.0.1 to 52.115.255.254 could I not just use that range as from start to end ip?

Comment: You could, but CIDR notation is a more compact and easier to remember form. If you work with networks, it's worth learning. It's widely used.

Comment: CIDR is much more efficient when matching address prefixes. With software-based routers/firewalls it uses less CPU cycles, and with hardware-based devices it uses just a single TCAM entry.

Comment: @Zac67: Exactly, and sometimes a range is internally converted to CIDR notation anyway. Therefore, by specifying just the host address range `52.112.0.1-52.115.255.254` instead of the whole `52.112.0.0/14` i.e. `52.112.0.0-52.115.255.255` you may actually end up adding `52.112.0.1/32`, `52.112.0.2/31`, ..., `52.113.0.0/16`, `52.114.0.0/16`, ..., `52.115.255.252/31` & `52.115.255.254/32`. Which is 34 separate CIDR ranges instead of the one.